# What is the background of allowAllProperties, why is it necessary here?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a form with a parameter that is mapped to an object storage. In a template I have form that sets this parameter with a list of checkboxes. Heres an overview of the action in the controller and the template.

*Controller*

```
/**
 * action list
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Redacted\Productfinder\Domain\Model\Category> $categories
 * @return void
 */
public function searchAction($categories=NULL) {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump(func_get_args());
    ...
}
```

*Template*

```
<f:for each="{categories}" as="option">
    <li class="category-{option.uid}" data-filter="{option.uid}">
        <label for="checkbox-category-{option.uid}">
            <f:form.checkbox name="categories" multiple="true" id="checkbox-category-{option.uid}" value="{option.uid}" checked="{x:condition.iterator.contains(haystack:'{filter.categories}', needle:'{option}', then:'checked')}" />
            <span class="title">{option.title}
        </label>
    </li>
</f:for>
```

This, so far, works like a charm. I'm now trying to set the $categories parameter with a link, but that doesn't work. I have a f:for loop with the categories.

If I set the Parameter to the single object like so, it is ignored. No error message, Extbase just ignores the value.

```
<f:link.action action="list" arguments="{categories:category}">{category.title}</f:link.action>
```

If I set the parameter to an array with that value, like so

```
<f:link.action action="list" arguments="{categories:{0:'{category}'}}">{category.title}</f:link.action>
```

Extbase tells me, that the Parameter cannot be mapped.

```
#1297759968: Exception while property mapping at property path "": It is not allowed to map property "0"
```

I've managed to figure out, that I can tell Extbase to allow the property mappging, and then resolve the raw uids into extbase objects, like so

```
        $propertyMappingConfiguration = $this->arguments->getArgument($property)->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
        $propertyMappingConfiguration->allowAllProperties();
```

I'd like to understand the background of this, why is this necessary to allow this for GET parameters, when it just works for POST? Am I doing something wrong, or is this by design?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed by design. If you use `<f:form.textfield.....` it isn't needed to set it expliciet like you do.

This is to prevent that unwanted items are past/persisted because someone changed the form manually.
So it's a security thing

Comment: I don't understand how that is different from setting paramters that map a single object? I can easily set a @param \Redacted\Productfinder\Domain\Model\Category $category as argument in a link, why not one that takes multiple values through an ObjectStorage? In both cases the PropertyMapper maps the values to objects, right? How does that improve the security?